# Ordenar valores sem repeti-los, em R

Tags: r

Criei uma nova coluna em um tibble, para utilizar como identificador de uma segunda coluna. Entretanto, há valores repetidos, e gostaria que esses valores repetidos possuíssem o mesmo identificador.

```
prec_med_novo <- mutate(prec_med, COD_SUBS = as.integer(length(25991)))

preco_med <- prec_med_novo[, c(37, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
                               24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36)]
preco_med
```

A coluna 37 (ou seja, a primeira, possui os valores que desejo alterar, e a coluna 1, os valores aos quais eles serão vinculados.

Comment: Quais são os nomes da 1ª e da 2ª colunas?

Comment: `length(25991)` é de classe `"integer"`, não precisa de `as.integer`. E o valor é sempre 1.

Comment: cod_subs, substância, respectivamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui vai uma solução com o pacote `dplyr`

Atribuir à variável identificadora os números da correspondência entre `substancia` e `unique(substancia)`.

```
library(dplyr)

prec_med %>% 
  mutate(cod_subs = match(substancia, unique(substancia)))
```

Comment: Em ambos os casos, ele atribuiu um valor á substância e, caso essa substância se repetisse, colocou o próximo valor. Mas, ainda assim, atribuiu um mesmo valor a substâncias diferentes. No caso, preciso que a substância A sempre possua o valor 1, independentemente de quantas vezes se repita; a substância B possua o valor 2, assim sucessivamente

Comment: @LeonardoGonçalvesdaFonseca Obrigado pela explicação adicional. Veja agora depois da edição.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!